# Using xkcd to plot a hr diagram but all the labels are so big

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm trying to plot a hr diagram in python using matplotlib and I want to make it look a little more appealing to children by making it look like a drawing with xkcd. I'm not getting any errors with my code but the axes labels and title on the resulting graph are so big you can't even read what they're saying. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

[image: HR diagram]

```
import glob
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
from sys import exit
import random
from numpy import exp
import math
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
import csv
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
plt.xkcd()

plt.style.use('dark_background')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

with open("gaia_stars - Sheet1 (1).tsv") as tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    tsvfile.next()
    for line in tsvreader:
        temperature.append(line[5]) 
        magnitude.append(line[21])     

plt.figure(figsize=(22,22))
plt.scatter(temperature, magnitude, c=temperature, cmap=plt.get_cmap('RdYlBu'), marker='*')        
plt.ylabel('Magnitude',fontsize=17)
plt.xlabel('Temperature /K',fontsize=17) 
plt.title('Hertzsprung-Russell Diagram',fontsize=20)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.xscale('log')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
for line in ax.get_xticklines() + ax.get_yticklines():
    line.set_markersize(10)

plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=12)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=12)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: If this is meant to be understood by children, it will fail for other reasons than font-weight. But if you want to keep the comic sans ms font, you may simply want to increase font size.

Comment: would you mind to share the dataset used, so your plot can be reproduced?